# Blender repeatedly syncs all objects while using the background mode

Tags: python, eevee-render-engine, gpu

I'm running Blender in the background mode using a Python script that moves the camera, renders an image and performs some processing on the image. However, when I run the script in background mode, there is an extra time spent for syncing all the objects in the scene for each render (see an example below). This doesn't happen when I open Blender and run the script. However, I'm running this remotely on a GPU server, so it's not practical to open Blender.

Syncing probably happens regardless of background mode is used or not. I suspect that it is the printing out "Syncing..." that consumes an additional time.

Is there a way to disable the sync messages for the background mode? I'm using Blender 2.83 with Eevee on Ubuntu 20.04 and Optix for GPU rendering.

```
Fra:13 Mem:462.32M (0.00M, Peak 462.34M) | Time:00:00.03 | Syncing Camera
Fra:13 Mem:462.32M (0.00M, Peak 462.34M) | Time:00:00.03 | Syncing Point
Fra:13 Mem:462.32M (0.00M, Peak 462.34M) | Time:00:00.03 | Syncing Point.001
Fra:13 Mem:462.32M (0.00M, Peak 462.34M) | Time:00:00.03 | Syncing Point.002
Fra:13 Mem:462.32M (0.00M, Peak 462.34M) | Time:00:00.03 | Syncing Josh
Fra:13 Mem:464.16M (0.00M, Peak 478.32M) | Time:00:00.07 | Rendering 1 / 64 samples
Fra:13 Mem:462.33M (0.00M, Peak 478.32M) | Time:00:00.12 | Rendering 26 / 64 samples
Fra:13 Mem:462.33M (0.00M, Peak 478.32M) | Time:00:00.15 | Rendering 51 / 64 samples
Fra:13 Mem:462.33M (0.00M, Peak 478.32M) | Time:00:00.17 | Rendering 64 / 64 samples
Fra:13 Mem:454.22M (0.00M, Peak 478.32M) | Time:00:00.17 | Sce: Scene Ve:0 Fa:0 La:0
Saved: '/home/guel/projects/image_warp/results/blender_single/Josh/000_LR_slow_n0/000_LR_slow_n0_100_imgs_ref/0013.png'
 Time: 00:00.22 (Saving: 00:00.04)

(  0.0001 sec |   0.0001 sec) Importing OBJ '/home/guel/projects/image_warp/../../data/JOSH_T025_MSPL_v1_baked/Frame_00014.obj'...
  (  0.0002 sec |   0.0001 sec) Parsing OBJ file...
    (  0.2065 sec |   0.2062 sec) Done, loading materials and images...
    (  0.2073 sec |   0.2070 sec) Done, building geometries (verts:10580 faces:20000 materials: 1 smoothgroups:0) ...
    (  0.3888 sec |   0.3885 sec) Done.
  (  0.3890 sec |   0.3888 sec) Finished importing: '/home/guel/projects/image_warp/../../data/JOSH_T025_MSPL_v1_baked/Frame_00014.obj'
Progress: 100.00%

Fra:14 Mem:463.01M (0.00M, Peak 463.03M) | Time:00:00.02 | Syncing Camera
Fra:14 Mem:463.01M (0.00M, Peak 463.03M) | Time:00:00.02 | Syncing Point
Fra:14 Mem:463.01M (0.00M, Peak 463.03M) | Time:00:00.02 | Syncing Point.001
Fra:14 Mem:463.01M (0.00M, Peak 463.03M) | Time:00:00.02 | Syncing Point.002
Fra:14 Mem:463.01M (0.00M, Peak 463.03M) | Time:00:00.02 | Syncing Josh
Fra:14 Mem:480.86M (0.00M, Peak 495.02M) | Time:00:00.13 | Rendering 1 / 64 samples
Fra:14 Mem:479.03M (0.00M, Peak 495.02M) | Time:00:00.18 | Rendering 26 / 64 samples
Fra:14 Mem:479.03M (0.00M, Peak 495.02M) | Time:00:00.22 | Rendering 51 / 64 samples
Fra:14 Mem:479.03M (0.00M, Peak 495.02M) | Time:00:00.23 | Rendering 64 / 64 samples
Fra:14 Mem:470.92M (0.00M, Peak 495.02M) | Time:00:00.24 | Sce: Scene Ve:0 Fa:0 La:0
Saved: '/home/guel/projects/image_warp/results/blender_single/Josh/000_LR_slow_n0/000_LR_slow_n0_100_baseline/imgs_pred/0014.png'
 Time: 00:00.28 (Saving: 00:00.04)
```

Comment: Try to enable persistent data: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.0/render/cycles/render_settings/performance.html#bpy-types-rendersettings-use-persistent-data (Render -> Performance -> Final Render -> Persistent Data).

Comment: I'm currently using Eevee, is there anything similar for it? Otherwise I could try switching to Cycles, I have no special reason to use Eevee.